# Restrict Result Source to Specific Web Application

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search

We have two web applications (Documents/Portal), and have created two result sources, one for each web application.

In the result source, I have configured the query to only return results from the current path, but results are being returned from both web applications.

Web Applications:

```
http://testdoc2013

http://testportal
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I realized my syntax was incorrect, and resolved the issue.

it should be

```
{?{searchTerms} PATH://testdoc2013}
{?{searchTerms} PATH://testportal}
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered