# Configuring Sharepoint Content Sources

Tags: 2013, search-results, result-source

I have two web applications. I set up both to be crawled (Search Service Application: Edit Content Source>Start addresses, Crawl everything under the hostname for each start address).

If I understand correctly, those two paths would be considered under "local Sharepoint results" in the list of result sources. However, when I search from the search center, only results from the first web application are seen. Nothing is visible from the second web application.

What are possible things to check to include site collections on that second web application in my result sources?

It seems I have the opposite problem from [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100639/restrict-result-source-to-specific-web-application) OP. I want to restrict results, but they have to be included before I restrict them.

EDIT: 
In my search service application, I've created a result source called Build Eagle. The query text is `{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople} Path:http://www.buildeagle.com`. When I `test query`, I get 72 results. (Logged into central administration as me). I have a search site set up at `http://www.buildeagle.com/sites/search`. My search center is `http://buildeagle.com/sites/search`. When I go to `http://www.buildeagle.com/sites/search/results.aspx`, and edit the **search results** webpart, I set the result source to the `Build Eagle (service)`, and my query text is simply `{SearchBoxQuery}`. I then go to test>show more, and enter various `{SearchBoxQuery}`. No results show up. Could it have something to do with the fact that the search is in a different site collection?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the crawl logs. Are both your start addresses retrieving results? If its permissions, does your crawl account have access? If that is working, do you have access. Search only returns items that you have access to.

Comment: The content sources are getting crawled, without errors. In the search application, I create a result source. When I do a test search, my test doesn't show up, although I've verified that path is crawled. When I go to the search site collection, and set my result source to be the one from the search application, Sharepoint doesn't return any results. Could it be a permissions issue? How do I know?

Comment: Do you have access to the content? Can you log in as your Crawl Account and try the search again?

Comment: I'm logged in as the farm administrator.

Comment: Log on as yourself or the Crawl Account and try the search again. Farm Admin does not necessarily have access to the content. In Search your account has to hace access to the content for results to show.

Comment: I logged in as both the site collection administrator and the crawl account, and I got the same results both ways. PS, I added more details to the original question